# user WhitespaceTrimmer plugin c#

Tags: imageresizer

I have imageresizing.net creative version,
i have downloaded the free version from imageresizing.net.

i want to use WhitespaceTrimmer plugin from c# code behind, dint able to find any simple sample , can any body help with any simple example

the version i downloaded have source code, and found some code of  WhitespaceTrimmer, but that does not seems the complete.

Do i need to separately download it for creative version?

**EDIT**

I tried this code but no effect

```
 System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                       ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(orgimg, stream, new Instructions("trim.threshold=80&trim.percentpadding=0.5"), false, true));
 orgimg = new Bitmap(stream);
```

I also change code to

```
   ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(orgimg, stream, new Instructions("trim.threshold=80&trim.percentpadding=0.5")));
```

But no effect. similar image is generating. after this function.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All [ImageResizer plugins and the complete source is on GitHub](https://github.com/imazen/resizer), and is also included in the download.

Like all ImageResizer plugins, [the WhitespaceTrimmer functionality activates based on querystring commands](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/whitespacetrimmer). If you are using them from code-behind, you simply construct a querystring there instead like so:

```cs
ImageBuilder.Current.Build("~/images/source.jpg","~/images/dest.jpg", 
  new Instructions("trim.threshold=80&trim.percentpadding=0.5"));
```

Comment: I want to pass bitmap stream, and then want to have return bitmap stream, the similar way i did for resize image, is it possible " orgimg = ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(orgimg, rsetting);"  orgimg is a bitstream

Comment: I tried this way, but no effect..
{code}
 string trimwhitespaceparams = "trim.threshold=80&trim.percentpadding=0.5"; 
                         ResizeSettings rsetting = new ResizeSettings(trimwhitespaceparams);
                         orgimg = ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(orgimg, rsetting);{/code}

Comment: also i am not able to find the instructions method, which name space i have to add, or do i need to run the source code to get the dll and then add in my project :o

Comment: Did you *install* the WhitespaceTrimmer plugin? If you used the code from your comment, 'orgimg' would be a raw Bitmap instance, not an encoded image, so ImageResizer would be prevented from encoding it properly. Give ImageResizer an output Stream, MemoryStream, or file path instead for proper behavior.

Comment: I dint install anything, but i am able to set max height and width,

Comment: "Destination may be a string or Stream" i am getting this error, i am using "ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(orgimg,orgimg, new Instructions("trim.threshold=80&trim.percentpadding=0.5"),false,true));" as i want to have bitmap stream in return

Comment: I am able to find the instruction class, and executing your code , but it has no effect. finally i have to send a bitmap object, and want to have bitmap object in return, but your code itself creating destination object with no effect

Comment: If you don't install WhitespaceTrimmer, there will be no effect. Furthermore, you cannot pass the same stream for input and output. If you wish to get an answer, you will need to provide exact source code and exact error messages in your answer.

Comment: I updated the post with code, also how will i install this plugin for visual studio, and also i will need it to install on server, if i push code to server. However, i have used resizer for changing height and width and i was able to do without any installation.

Comment: I went through installation process, and found first i will required to Nuget packet manager, then will able to install it, but what about after moving the code to server.

Comment: Ok, I have installed, and it seems working on my local machine,

Comment: One thing, this is what i have downloaded in free version, so what required me to purchase it ?

Comment: How can we provide the minimum height and width to crop